# Combobox Focus is not setting

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to set combobox box in constructor. But some how it's not set true so, Required field validation is fired and I am not able to change value of combobox. Based on combobox selection Controls is hide and show. My code is :

```
public CompanyAddEdit(MainForm form, int totalItems)
{
    passedForm = form;
    InitializeComponent();            
    BindCompanyType();
    Id = totalItems;
    xmlDocPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Companies.xml");
    xDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlDocPath);   
    cmbbx_companyType.Focus();
}
```

Comment: No it's still display on next control.

Comment: instead of `cmbbx_companyType.Focus()` try using `cmbbx_companyType.Select()`.

Comment: @vikscool, Thanks its working

Comment: @vikscool please provide your answer in an answer form, so that this question can be updated to have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you can do to have the `combobox` focused on the constructor.

1. Set the `Tabindex` property of the `combobox` to the lowest.
2. You can call the `cmbbx_companyType.Select()` to set the focus after it is visible.

Here is an updated snippet of your code with `Select()`:

```
public CompanyAddEdit(MainForm form, int totalItems)
{
  passedForm = form;
  InitializeComponent();            
  BindCompanyType();
  Id = totalItems;
  xmlDocPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Companies.xml");
  xDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlDocPath);   
  cmbbx_companyType.Select();
}
```

Comment: So what is the difference with the `focus()` and the `select()` method ?

Comment: Also you forgot about `this.ActiveControl = cmbbx_companyType;` possibility

Comment: The `focus()` will only work when the control is visible(i.e. when the form is displayed or you can call it in the `onShown()` event) where `select()` set the value and will set the focus/Activate the control when it is displayed. And yes `this.ActiveControl` is also a possibility whereas I provided the `select()` only because it is easy to understand.

Comment: yes I know that but I mean that you should write this explanation in your answer to make it complete